# How to empty an array while async function is changing the array

Tags: javascript, async-await

I want to empty an array when the user clicks a button a second time while an async function is running.

At the moment because it is an async function I am adding to the array rather than emptying it when you click the button a second time while the function is running.

Comment: And ... do you wish to show your source code?

Comment: My magic ball is in the shop so I am not able to see into your computer. Can you add code so we can help you.

Comment: I am not sure that is the duplicate there.... thinking that is wrong.

Comment: @epascarello Possibly but question also so vague with no real code to debug I figured let onus be on OP to improve question if that is not the issue